# if statement inside isset function not working

Tags: php

I am trying to validate my form using php, I am using the isset function to check if the submit button has been clicked. when I click the submit button the code inside the isset function does not execute.

```
//html


    <div style="width:800px; margin:0px auto 0px auto;">
       <table>
           <tr>
            <td width ="60%" valign="top">
             <h2>join to find friends today</h2>
            </td>

            <td width ="40%" valign="top">
              <h2>Sign up below</h2>

              <form action ="" method"POST">
              <input type="text" name="fname" size ="25"                     placeholder="firstname" /><br/><br/>
              <input type="text" name="lname" size ="25" placeholder="lastname" /><br/><br/>
              <input type="text" name="username" size ="25" placeholder="username"/><br/><br/>
              <input type="text" name="email" size ="25" placeholder="email"/><br/><br/>
              <input type="text" name="email2" size ="25" placeholder="confirm email"/><br/><br/>
              <input type="text" name="password" size ="25" placeholder="password"/><br/><br/>
              <input type="text" name="password2" size ="25" placeholder="confirm password"/><br/><br/>
              <input type="submit" name="reg" value="sign up">

              </form>

            </td>
           </tr>

       </table> 

//php code 

<?php


//declaring variables to prevent errors
$fn = ""; //First Name
$ln = ""; //Last Name
$un = ""; //Username
$em = ""; //Email  
$em2 = ""; //Email 2
$pswd = ""; //Password
$pswd2 = ""; // Password 2
$d = ""; // Sign up Date
$u_check = ""; // Check if username exists
$error ="";

  if (isset($_POST['reg'])) {

//registration form
$fn = strip_tags($_POST['fname']);
$ln = strip_tags($_POST['lname']);
$un = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$em = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$em2 = strip_tags($_POST['email2']);
$pswd = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
$pswd2 = strip_tags($_POST['password2']);
$d = date("Y-m-d"); // Year - Month - Day


if(empty($fn)){

 echo 'empty';

 } 
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: First you are missing a bracket and second what code should execute ?!

Comment: the if statement to check if the firstname field is empty

Comment: You forgot an `=` in your `<form>` tag. So: `method"POST"` => `method="post"`

Comment: thank you for your help it fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

You forgot an `=` in your `<form>` tag.

Replace

```
<form action ="" method"POST">
```

with

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

and it should work.